# How can I use Ruby RSpec to test a class that adds an observer?

Tags: ruby, rspec, observer-pattern, resque

My task is implemented like this:

```
class MyTask
    @queue = :queue_name
    include BaseTask
end

module BaseTask
    include Observable
    def perform
        add_observer(MyObserver.new)
        ...
        changed
        notify_observers
    end
end
```

I have a Resque task that `include Observable` with the `perform` method calling `add_observer`, `changed`, and `notify_observers`. How do I test `BaseTask` with `RSpec`? I initialized `MyTask` and called `task.perform`. I tried `Observable.should_receive(:add_observer)`, `MyTask.any_instance.should_receive(:add_observer)`, `BaseTask.should_receive(:add_observer)`, but they aren't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to check message expectations on an *instance* of `MyTask`.
For example,

```
it "is observable" do
  task = MyTask.new
  task.should_receive :add_observer
  task.should_receive :changed
  task.should_receive :notify_observers

  task.perform
end
```

Ideally, I wouldn't do it this way since a lot of message expectations on the object under test are being made.  Instead, I might check some external state that is a result of calling `perform`.

**EDIT**
If you want to check instance methods on `MyObserver`, you could do something like this, before calling `perform`:

```
observer = mock
MyObserver.stub(:new).and_return(observer)
observer.should_receive(:some_method) #replace `some_method` with whatever instance method you want
```

Comment: How can I test that `MyObserver` is called with `:update`? I added `MyObserver.any_instance.should_receive(:update)` before `task.perform` but it says `update` isn't being called. But I know it is because the `puts` inside `update` are executing.

Comment: I updated my answer to show an example of checking `MyObserver`.